# Insert stored procedure plus static value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I am trying to insert the results from multiple stored procedures into a temp table. However I would also like to add another static value in each instance that is not part of these results to the table, but I am not sure about the syntax to do this.

Here's where I am at so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #table (
STATIC              INT, --STATIC NUMBER
SP1                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 1
SP2                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 2
SP3                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 3
);

INSERT INTO #table values('1'), EXEC stored_procedure 'param_1', 'param_2';
INSERT INTO #table values('2'), EXEC stored_procedure 'param_3', 'param_4';
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way of doing that.

Comment: You can't mix some values or expressions with the results of an SP while inserting on a table. Either you use a default constraint on the temp table, update the records afterwards or make the SP return the value.

Comment: It can be done if the stored proc was rewritten as a table function, although this isn't always possible

Comment: Do the `INSERT EXEC` and then `UPDATE` Static to whatever value you want where it is NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't quite do it the way you want, but you could `INSERT`,`UPDATE`, `INSERT`,`UPDATE`.

```
CREATE TABLE #table (
STATIC              INT, --STATIC NUMBER
SP1                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 1
SP2                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 2
SP3                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 3
);

INSERT INTO #table (SP1,SP2,SP3)
EXEC stored_procedure 'param_1', 'param_2';
UPDATE #table
SET STATIC = 1
WHERE STATIC IS NULL;

INSERT INTO #table (SP1,SP2,SP3)
EXEC stored_procedure 'param_3', 'param_4';
UPDATE #table
SET STATIC = 2
WHERE STATIC IS NULL;
```

Assuming that the Stored procedure's are returning 3 columns in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into a temp table and then join:

```
CREATE TABLE #sp (
SpKey               INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, --use for join
SP1                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 1
SP2                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 2
SP3                 INT, --STORED PROCEDURE COL 3
);

CREATE TABLE #static (
StaticKey           INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, --use for join
Value               INT
);

INSERT INTO #sp EXEC stored_procedure 'param_1', 'param_2'
INSERT INTO #static VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO #sp EXEC stored_procedure 'param_3', 'param_4'
INSERT INTO #static VALUES (2)

SELECT * INTO #table
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM #static
INNER JOIN #sp ON #static.StaticKey = #sp.SpKey) sub
```